# Simple mail send with fetch js and php

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I'm trying to send message to my email using fetch() and php.

handle event

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = { name: this.state.name, phone: this.state.phone };
    fetch('/mail.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        this.setState({ success: true })
      }
    })
  }
```

mail.php code

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $to = "mymail@gmail.com";
    $subject = 'Subj';
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $message = 'Name: '.$data['name'].' Phone: '.$data['phone'];
    $success = mail($to, $subject, $message);
    if ($success) {
        echo "Success!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Fail";
    }
}
?>
```

Using this because I was using it before with ajax() and it works.

I'm running my app at server, calling handler and getting "ok", but actually I don't get message on my email. I'm newbie, sorry if it's wrong way to achieve sending message to mail. I can't event know what data  is getting php and where I am wrong..

Comment: Does your server have a mail server installed

Comment: Yes. I think so. I have used almost same php code in simple html pages (but with ajax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's works.
Just added JSON.stringify() in handler.

```
const data = JSON.stringify({ name: this.state.name, phone: this.state.phone });
```

And `if (isset($_POST))` in mail.php